# Check before Insert Command T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert, sql-update

I have a stored procedure that does an update command to refresh the past eight weeks of data and then I was running an insert to add in yesterdays data which wouldnt be present at the time of the update.

However, I feel that I should have sometype of check in my code that checks to see if yesterday is already present before running the insert, just in case I ever want to run the procedure again (i think the insert would duplicate data) - does that make sense?

Thank you for any assistance offered.

Dave

Comment: Yes.  In some cases, it makes sense to check if data already exists before creating duplicates.

Comment: Is there a deeper question besides whether this makes sense or not? Are you worried about something?

Comment: Yes if you think that the integrity of your data would be compromised then by all means you should check

Comment: In my opinion, will be better if you would publish the table and the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called [UPSERT](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/upsert) (UPdate or inSERT).

If you are on SQL Server 2008 or a later version, you can use the `MERGE` Syntax. More on that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx):

If you are on an older version, you will have to check if the record exists using the Primary Key, and then do an `INSERT` if it doesn't exist, or the `UPDATE` if it does.

Here are examples of both approaches:

*[ **CAUTION:** Using the `MERGE` option may lead to race conditions and could lead to unpredictable situations [per this article](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx). (Thanks @Bohdan for the tip). ]*

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertUnitMeasure
    @UnitMeasureCode nchar(3),
    @Name nvarchar(25)
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- Update the row if it exists.    
    UPDATE Production.UnitMeasure
    SET Name = @Name
    WHERE UnitMeasureCode = @UnitMeasureCode
-- Insert the row if the UPDATE statement failed.   
    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0 )
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Production.UnitMeasure (UnitMeasureCode, Name)
        VALUES (@UnitMeasureCode, @Name)
    END
END;
GO

-- Test the procedure and return the results.
EXEC InsertUnitMeasure @UnitMeasureCode = 'ABC', @Name = 'Test Value';
SELECT UnitMeasureCode, Name FROM Production.UnitMeasure
WHERE UnitMeasureCode = 'ABC';
GO

-- Rewrite the procedure to perform the same operations using the MERGE statement.
-- Create a temporary table to hold the updated or inserted values from the OUTPUT clause.

CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable
    (ExistingCode nchar(3),
     ExistingName nvarchar(50),
     ExistingDate datetime,
     ActionTaken nvarchar(10),
     NewCode nchar(3),
     NewName nvarchar(50),
     NewDate datetime
    );
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.InsertUnitMeasure
    @UnitMeasureCode nchar(3),
    @Name nvarchar(25)
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    MERGE Production.UnitMeasure AS target
    USING (SELECT @UnitMeasureCode, @Name) AS source (UnitMeasureCode, Name)
    ON (target.UnitMeasureCode = source.UnitMeasureCode)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET Name = source.Name
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
        INSERT (UnitMeasureCode, Name)
        VALUES (source.UnitMeasureCode, source.Name)
        OUTPUT deleted.*, $action, inserted.* INTO #MyTempTable;
END;
GO

-- Test the procedure and return the results.
EXEC InsertUnitMeasure @UnitMeasureCode = 'ABC', @Name = 'New Test Value';
EXEC InsertUnitMeasure @UnitMeasureCode = 'XYZ', @Name = 'Test Value';
EXEC InsertUnitMeasure @UnitMeasureCode = 'ABC', @Name = 'Another Test Value';

SELECT * FROM #MyTempTable;
-- Cleanup 
DELETE FROM Production.UnitMeasure WHERE UnitMeasureCode IN ('ABC','XYZ');
DROP TABLE #MyTempTable;
GO
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: +1: I think calling it an UPSERT is confusing since this is technical jargon at best (though I've never heard it used). I think the `MERGE` is the correct and best answer though.

Comment: I didn't come up with `UPSERT`. It's an industry jargon for an INSERT or UPDATE Operation. Even Microsoft and other software vendors refer to the operation as such. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/09/15/windows-azure-tables-introducing-upsert-and-query-projection.aspx

Comment: @Shiva: `dbo.InsertUnitMeasure` isn't safe under high concurrency. One solution is to encapsulate those SQL statements within a SERIALIZABLE transaction + an UNIQUE index.

Comment: Thanks @BogdanSahlean for the tip. I'll see if I can let Microsoft know so they can update their example on MSDN (the source of that code as I credited at the end).

Comment: Also, [MERGE isn't safe](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @BogdanSahlean I updated my answer to warn OP of the consequences.

Comment: Does this even answer the question? It is unclear what was asked.